# Calling services by factory methods

Tags: php, symfony

Right now I can call services from controllers in the following way:

```
$this -> get('myservice') -> doSomething();
```

But I want to do this according to the factory method pattern, like this:

```
ServiceFactory :: createMyservice() -> doSomething();
```

The problem is that I can't pass parameters with the second method, they're null.

---

services.yml:

```
parameters:

services:
    myservice:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Myservice
        factory: [Appbundle\Factory\ServiceFactory, createMyservice]
        arguments:
            - "%kernel.root_dir%"
```

ServiceFactory.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Factory;

use AppBundle\Service\MyService;

class ServiceFactory
{

    public static function createMyservice($rootDir)
    {
        var_dump($rootDir); // NULL
        $object = new Myservice($rootDir);
        return $object;
    }

}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Why? The symfony service container uses already your service factory. Don'T use static methods in your controllers.

Comment: From a controller use $myService = $this->get('myservice'); instead of $myService = ServiceFactory::createMyService(); which is what I suspect you are doing.